# Does FirebaseApp.configure() actually raise exceptions?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

The documentation implies it will raise an exception if any part of the configuration fails but it doesn't seem possible to actually catch an exception (Swift 4.)  Certainly, one cannot wrap the statement in a do..catch block.  If it fails, is my app doomed to just crash or continue and try (and fail) to operate without Firebase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FirebaseApp.configure()` will only crash if there's something wrong with the configuration file that you download from Firebase's console.

If it worked for you one time, there won't be a reason for it to crash later unless you change the configuration file. So no need to try to catch the error or any special effort.

Comment: Network issues or the like?  Or is it all internal configuration?

Comment: Check the documentation, this only raises an exception if the configuration fails. Configuration is local, has nothing to do with connecting to Firebase. Here's the link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasecore/api/reference/Classes/FIRApp#/c:objc(cs)FIRApp(cm)configure

Comment: I did read that but it doesn't really explain what it does.  If it is all internal then it would seem to only cause dev/test-time failures rather than runtime failure.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: It also crashes if you call it later than app initialization time. I understand why, but this is unacceptable. It should never crash, just fail gracefully. (This is with a valid config file - it doesn't crash when called on app startup.)